# Sorting a nested list based on another nested list

Tags: python, sorting, string-matching, nested-lists

I have two nested lists, x1 and x2. I need to resort x2 based on the order of x1[0][0].

I have tried to used sort() and some of lambda x but not entirely sure how to approach this.

```
x1 = [["d", 0.4, 1],
     ["c", 0.5, 2],
     ["b", 0.3, 3],
     ["a", 0.5, 4]]

x2 = [["c", 4, 1],
     ["d", 2, 2],
     ["a", 6, 3],
     ["b", 6, 4]]
```

I expect to get the following output for the reordered x2

```
x2 = [["d", 2, 2],
     ["c", 4, 1],
     ["b", 6, 4],
     ["a", 6, 3]]
```

I can't rely on reordering based on alphabetical order as the dataset I am using differs to this and I may run into other problems. Ideally, I need to write something that will simply match each nested list to the order x2 appears in x1 based only on the first element of each nested list (which is always a string).

I need to do this using only pythons standard library.

Comment: The example is not clear. This would be equivalent to sorting based on the sorted order of first elements of `x2` itself.

Comment: @Austin I have just updated it to be more reflective of what I am after. Sorry I was unclear. A basic sort would have worked on what I had but not on my real data set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can build a dict that maps the keys in `x1` to its index using `enumerate`, and then sort `x2` with a key function that returns the index from the mapped key:

```
order = {k: i for i, (k, *_) in enumerate(x1)}
x2.sort(key=lambda t: order[t[0]])
```

`x2` becomes:

```
[['a', 3], ['b', 1], ['c', 4], ['d', 2]]
```

Comment: @blhsing, Thanks for your help! I just updated by data to be more reflective of the real dataset that I am using. I get a ValueError using your solution on my data due to having an extra value.

Comment: Glad to be of help. I've updated my answer accordingly then.

Answer (score 2):

try following:

```py
x1 = [["a", 1],
     ["b", 2],
     ["c", 3],
     ["d", 4]]

x2 = [["b", 1],
     ["d", 2],
     ["a", 3],
     ["c", 4]]

x2.sort(key=lambda k: dict(x1)[k[0]])

x2
```

this outputs

```
[['a', 3], ['c', 4], ['b', 1], ['d', 2]]
```